# Jenkins triggering jobs if master changes, although configured otherwise

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

We have a Jenkins instance completely configured via CasC. As soon as we rolled out this version we noticed some issues on how `github-branch-source` and `workflow-multibranch` behave.

We are trying to scan an Org, identifying all repositories with Jenkinsfile, but not triggering the build jobs, especially for branches where only the target (master) has changed. We have achieved some level of success with the following configuration:

1. Disabled "Child Scan Triggers"
2. Setting "Ignore rebuilding merge branches when only the target branch changed" from `basic-branch-build-strategies`
3. Setting "Skip initial build on first branch indexing"

With these, we are able to identify new repositories with Jenkinsfile during an OrgScan but not triggering any PR build unnecessarily.

The configurations above work fine unless Jenkins restarts. In the event of any restart the repository scan triggers, and although we have "Ignore rebuilding merge branches when only the target branch changed", PRs, where only the master changed, are scheduled to be built, as below,

```
    Checking pull request #5417
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
Changes detected: PR-5417 (7202a80c95188db87f98ccf62157fdd76d41a206+81e38fbefa404bcbad7968ad07cd522acf68be8b (3017360542722f016bb24c584bf55b3fa88f4921) → 7202a80c95188db87f98ccf62157fdd76d41a206+65343d82d5966e02b2889a4b2c9582e8d3e46362 (02e307214a15d7f192236994695578d6b8dacb08))
Scheduled build for branch: PR-5417
```

This is a huge problem, especially knowing that at some point in time we may have over 50 PRs opened at the same time for a single repository on that Org, not mentioning the other repositories. This has not only consumed a lot of resources as it has rendered our Jenkins useless until this high volume is processed.

Is there any way to guarantee new repository scans will not be triggered by Jenkins restart? Or even better, is there any way to enforce *Ignore rebuilding merge branches when only the target branch changed* on a repository level?

Comment: I might not have been clear, but we want to trigger jobs only when the GitHub webhook created for each repository notifies Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Ok folks, I guess I found the answer reading through the `branch-api` plugin source code.

Looks like the problem is here, https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/branch/MultiBranchProject.java#L2246-L2257 (as of 07/15/2020, v2.5.6). It will always return true for any branch/PR if any of the build strategies returns `true`.

I had the following three strategies together:

1. `jenkins.branch.buildstrategies.basic.ChangeRequestBuildStrategyImpl`
2. `jenkins.branch.buildstrategies.basic.NamedBranchBuildStrategyImpl`
3. `jenkins.branch.buildstrategies.basic.SkipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing`

Turns out `SkipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing` will always return `true` if it isn't the first branch indexing of that repository, rendering the configurations on `ChangeRequestBuildStrategyImpl` useless.

I am not sure if this is the expected behavior of the `branch-api` plugin and created a bug on their Jira, https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63088. While there is no fix to the problem, I removed `SkipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing` and bit the bullet assuming a fresh instance of Jenkins will have a huge overhead to build all PRs and Branches when it runs the first scan.

I hope this explanation can help someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way around this until you have built it at least once.

Since `SkipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing` suppresses the initial build trigger after registering a new job, the `build.xml` does not become available yet to store the change request information. In absence of this information, when Jenkins receives a subsequent hook, it is unable to perform a comparison to decide whether a build should be triggered or not. Therefore, it looks up the configuration to find that a job already exists for this (i.e., it does not qualify as an initial build) and that change requests are enabled. So it goes ahead and triggers a build.

After the first build, the file becomes available at `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<my-repo>/branches/PR-1/builds/1/build.xml`. Among other details, it contains the following information pertaining to change requests (pay attention to the hashes):

```
<revision class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.PullRequestSCMRevision" plugin="github-branch-source@2.5.8">
    <head class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.PullRequestSCMHead">
        <name>PR-1</name>
        <merge>true</merge>
        <number>1</number>
        <target>
            <name>master</name>
        </target>
        <sourceOwner>ORG</sourceOwner>
        <sourceRepo>my-repo</sourceRepo>
        <sourceBranch>my/feature-branch</sourceBranch>
        <origin class="jenkins.scm.api.SCMHeadOrigin$Default" plugin="scm-api@2.6.3"/>
    </head>
    <target class="jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$SCMRevisionImpl" plugin="git@4.0.0">
        <head class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.BranchSCMHead" reference="../../head/target"/>
        <hash>9501c1d2dd5b29nso488909ec2b0aac14208b28</hash>
    </target>
    <baseHash>9501c1d2dd5b29nso488909ec2b0aac14208b28</baseHash>
    <pullHash>du65a39j39j24368ab6561d260093e78d69b20549</pullHash>
    <mergeHash>9d62w889092ef74c6a7a2d67897e91d70wb73hs8</mergeHash>
</revision>
```

Comment: I don't know. I had a different observation. Even after the job had run incorrectly several times, triggering builds when only the master branch had changed, after I removed `SkipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing` it started to behave correctly, not triggering builds if the only change was the targe. After analyzing the plugin source code, this session, https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/branch/MultiBranchProject.java#L2246-L2257, I notice that `SkipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing` will always return `true`, deafeating the other strategies.

Comment: By that I mean the strategies are evaluated as a short-circuit `OR`, meaning if any of them are `true` it doesn't matter if another one returns `false`. The trigger will be pushed. I don't know if it's by design, but honestly I think they should be evaluated as `AND`, meaning if strategyA && strategyB && strategyN.